# SQL code to select from multiple XML files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to trying to select from XML files which are called "StockStatusReport#####.XML" (##### = numbers which change).  There are multiple files called "StockStatusReport#####" and I would like to select all of the "StockStatusReport" XML files. How would I go about selecting all of the XML files which start with "StockStatusReport" ?

My working code is below, but only works if the filename is specified in full as shown:

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Test\StockStatusReport30597.XML', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an external job using script or managed language which first loads the files into a SQL server table one by one. Call the table something like "StockStatusQueue". Add some columns for book-keeping like `dtLoaded datetime`, `dtProcessed datetime`.

Once the XML data is in an XML-typed column your life will be much easier, and you can start using loops and stuff.